# HTML入力フォームの途中で、自動保存する機能はどうやって実装？

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

**HTML入力フォームの途中で、自動保存する機能について**
・スタック・オーバーフローのフォームにも適用されているようですが、これはどうやって実装しているのですか？
・クライアント側で完結？
・サーバへ送信？ データベースへ保存？
・何れでも良い？ 色々なやり方がある？？

Answer (score 3):

スタック・オーバーフローでの(書きかけな)フォームデータはブラウザや端末を変えても引き継がれるので、サーバー側でデータを保存しているのでしょう。

よくある「次回からログインIDの入力を省略」みたいなものは、Cookieを使ってクライアント側で保存する方法もあります。
不意にブラウザを閉じてしまった場合に備えて動的に保存するなら、Javascript(Jquery)等と組み合わせる必要があるかもしれません。

どんなデータを何処に保存したいかで実装方法も変わってくると思います。